# scp error when defining a "PATH" variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, variables, path, scp

So this is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/SomeFolder/file2.txt;     
scp -3 user@server1:/SomeFolder/file.txt user@server2:$PATH;
```

I get this error

> main.sh: line 3: scp: command not found

If I put `/SomeFolder/file2.txt` in place of of `"$PATH"` it still doesn't work - same error. It's only after I remove entire second line (`PATH` definition) does it work.

I simplified my script, the `PATH` is defined by executing a script inside another server but that doesn't matter. I tested it like what you see and I concluded that the error is due to `PATH` being defined in the first place.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use uppercase variable names in your scripts. These are conventionally reserved for environment variables, which often have effects on other programs.

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because `PATH` is a system variable that defines directories where the programs and scripts should be looked for. You can view its value by executing `echo $PATH`. In your script you are setting `PATH` to `/SomeFolder/file2.txt` so the program `scp` that is usually in `/usr/bin/` can't be found. Just change the name of variable `PATH` in your script to something else.